# Unable to Use Android USB Drivers on Windows 10

Tags: android, xamarin

Following the Standard instructions to make use of the USB Drivers for Android Development provided by Google here

http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html

Does not work on Windows 10

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) Right click on the Start menu and select Device Manager

2) Right click on the Android Device and select Update Driver

3) Select Browse my computer for driver software

4) Select Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer

5) Select have Disk and find the below location and paste in.

> ```
> <SDK Location>\extras\google\usb_driver
> ```

Default location might be like below.

> ```
> C:\Users\<your username>\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\extras\google\usb_driver
> ```

6) Click Next

7) Select the Android ADB Interface

8) Allow debugging on your device and your all set

You should now be able too easily develop on Xamarin or any other android platform and debug right to your device

Comment: I upvoted this because it got me the closest, but it didn't work 100% for me, so I posted [this question specific to my experience with the Sony Smartwatch 3](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34701709/613482)

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading to windows 10, I tried all methods other than using the OEM provided USB cable for connecting my Galaxy Alpha phone. On using the USB cable which came along with the phone, it instantly got connected to my windows 10 pc.

Comment: One possibility here is that using cheaper cables was not enough data throughput. I have had cheap cables that would not work with USB 2.0 or USB 3.0 devices. When buying Cables I always go with  the thicker more expensive ones, or make sure they are compatible with the newest USB standards now. That way they work on everything. I had that same problem at one point with my Galaxy for charging and data transfer

Answer (score 0):

I just found you need first to reboot windows (8/10) with feature **Disable Driver Signature enforcement** turned off, running command

```
shutdown /r /o
```

then selecting **Troubleshoot**, **Advanced options**, **Startup Settings**, **Restart** button and finally pressing **F7** to "Disable Driver Signature enforcement" (just temporary until next reboot) as described below:

http://www.top-password.com/blog/how-to-disable-driver-signature-enforcement-in-windows-10-8-7/

Then, after you plug in Android device, you can see it in **Device Manager**, click **Update Driver Software...**, **Browse My Computer for Driver Software**, **Let me pick from list of device ...**, then there should be a button **Have Disk** and you should be free to pick a directory with downloaded Android USB Driver.

At least this option worked for me with combination of various ARM devices.