# How to setup USB driver for ADB for Sony Smartwatch 3 on Windows 10

Tags: android, windows, adb, wear-os

I am trying to setup ADB debugging via a wired USB connection from my PC running Window 10 Pro (on a 64-bit Core i7) to my Sony Smartwatch 3.

My PC is generally setup for Android Development, including for Android Wear (e.g. ADB debugging my Nexus 5X phone or Samsung Gear Live watch both work fine).  I've enabled developer options on the watch, including "ADB Debugging".

I believe the problem is that I don't have a USB driver setup properly.  As far as I know, it should work with the "Google USB Driver", which I have installed, but nevertheless, I get the yellow triangle next to "Smartwatch 3" in device manager.

I tried to follow the instructions from ["Unable to Use Android USB Drivers on Windows 10"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33203839/unable-to-use-android-usb-drivers-on-windows-10), but I got this error dialog and could not proceed:

---

### Select Device

The folder you specified doesn't contain a compatible software driver for your device. If the folder contains a driver, make sure it is designed to work with Windows for x64-based systems.

---

### OK

Answer (score 3):

While I was writing this question, I managed to get it working!

Here's what I did:

**I followed the instruction from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33203839/unable-to-use-android-usb-drivers-on-windows-10):**

1) Right click on the Start menu and select Device Manager

2) Right click on the Android Device and select Update Driver

3) Select Browse my computer for driver software

4) Select Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer

**At this point, I chose "Android Device" (or one of the Android things anyway) and then "Android ADB Interface", rather than using the path to the Google USB Driver.**

Comment: Very nice. I think the last part depends on your PC set up. I tried this way originally on mine and was getting errors similar to the errors you received trying my solution. Glad you were able to get it to work!